# How to set up panther crawler with docker

Tags: docker, symfony, symfony-panther

`Dockerfile`:

```
# https://github.com/symfony/panther#docker-integration
FROM php:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev chromium && docker-php-ext-install zip
ENV PANTHER_NO_SANDBOX 1

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  crawler:
    build: .
    working_dir: /usr/src
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src
    command: /bin/sh -c "/usr/local/bin/composer install && php index.php"
```

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/panther": "^0.6.0"
    }
}
```

`index.php`:

```
<?php

// https://github.com/symfony/panther#basic-usage
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; // Composer's autoloader

$client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient();
$client->request('GET', 'https://api-platform.com'); // Yes, this website is 100% written in JavaScript
$client->clickLink('Support');

// Wait for an element to be rendered
$crawler = $client->waitFor('.support');

echo $crawler->filter('.support')->text();
$client->takeScreenshot('screen.png'); // Yeah, screenshot!
```

All files are in the same location. I run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up` and I'm getting following error:
`crawler_1  | Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Could not start chrome (or it crashed) after 30 seconds. in /usr/src/vendor/symfony/panther/src/ProcessManager/WebServerReadinessProbeTrait.php:51`

This is similar to https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/200, however in my case I'm not using panther for tests, but only to scrape, and I really don't know how to fix this. I think my problem might be related to invalid docker / docker-compose files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error. My solution was **install unzip** as it says in the [readme](https://github.com/symfony/panther/tree/master):

> "Warning: On *nix systems, the unzip command must be installed or you
>   will encounter an error similar to RuntimeException: sh: 1: exec:
>   /app/vendor/symfony/panther/src/ProcessManager/../../chromedriver-bin/chromedriver_linux64:
>   Permission denied (or chromedriver_linux64: not found). The underlying
>   reason is that PHP's ZipArchive doesn't preserve UNIX executable
>   permissions."

and finally, reinstall the panther library.